# Work around for jQuery draggable and resizeable on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

Trying to apply both draggable and resizeable with jQuery to an image does not work correctly. It will resize but not drag. Are there any known solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work fine if I wrap the `img` in a `div`:

`<div id="drag_resize"><img src="img.jpg"/></div>`

And then call resizeable and draggable on that `div`:

`$("#drag_resize").resizable().draggable();`

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/HNYVk/